# 2nd tap on Login button is not working in iPhone Salesforce (PhoneGap) application

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, salesforce, phonegap-plugins

```
My Xcode Version is 4.3.2
iOS Simulator Version is 5.1 
PhoneGap Version Cordova-1.8.1
```

I am working on a salesforce iPhone application. Here is my login screen:

[image]

When I click on login button it is leading me to salesforce login page:
[image]

and after that when ever I tap on Login button nothing is happening. It is working properly in iOS Simulator 4.3. Is this a browser compatibility issue?